# Handling large numbers of sockets with .NET

Tags: c#, sockets, c#-4.0

I'm looking at writing a application that need to be able to handle in the region of 200 connections / sec and was wondering if C# and .NET will handle this or if I need to really be looking at C++ to do this?

It looks like SocketAsyncEventArgs may be the way to go but thought id check before I plough in to it.

Each transaction should only last less than a second but could take up to 15 seconds each if that makes any difference.

Comment: What is the expected number of simultaneous connections?  200/sec with some number lasting up to 15 seconds (let's say 5% for fun) means that after 5 minutes you're going to have around 1000/simultaneous.

Comment: incoming or outgoing connections?

Answer (score 3):

You'll run into operating system limits if you try to maintain that level of usage. Your ephemeral ports will expire pretty quickly.

If you just need to handle *bursts* of large numbers of connections, then .NET should be as capable of handling it as C++; you may need to adjust the `backlog` parameter to `Listen`.

Comment: What's the upper limit on IIS, then?

Comment: @David: I have no idea. But I know that IIS can't bypass an operating system limit; you only have so many ephemeral ports, and the `TIME_WAIT` state will kill any 200-connections-per-second usage. You'd need a load balancer sitting in front of a farm to take that kind of sustained abuse.

Comment: +1 fair enough. Now tempted to go write a test to determine the OS limits.

Comment: As long as you can close the socket on the server side with an `RST` (turn linger off), you can avoid the accumulation of `TIME_WAIT` on the server. Alternatively design your protocol so that the client issues the active close and then it will go into `TIME_WAIT` and not the server.

Comment: any ide what the limits are?
Luckily 99% of disconnects will be by the client.

@David - if you do can you post the results
edited due to accidental posting before I was ready :)

Answer (score 2):

I've written about this kind of thing [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/12/one-million-tcp-connections.html).

As long as you can design your system to avoid accumulating sockets in `TIME_WAIT` on the server you should be OK from an OS point of view on anything VISTA or later. You can avoid `TIME_WAIT` on the server either by closing the socket on the server with linger turned off so that the TCP stack sends an `RST` rather than a `FIN` OR by having the client issue the active close and therefore going into `TIME_WAIT` rather than the server.

You need to think about the speed of your accepts, so use async accept calls and post a lot of them, also make the listen backlog quite large.

If you need some code to test your server, I have a 'multi client test harness' that's free to download from [here](http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2005/11/windows-tcpip-server-performance.html). It uses `ConnectEx()` to issue a configurable number of async connects simultaneously at a rate that is controllable by the command line. I talk about it's usage a bit more [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/10/stress-testing-wasp-using-the-echoservertest-program.html).

If you're thinking of using C++ rather than C# then I have some example servers available [here](http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2005/11/simple-echo-servers.html),  and a set of free I/O completion port based code available [here](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html).

THE most important thing, IMHO, is to make sure you are [testing for your desired level of scalability from Day 0](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/10/how-to-support-10000-or-more-concurrent-tcp-connections---part-2---perf-tests-from-day-0.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Cheers I'll have a look though it all.